# Manejo de índices en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Quisiera saber sobre la creación y manejo de índices cuando se involucra varias columnas; por ejemplo en la tabla a parte de la `primary key` debo crear varios índices los cuales como se sabe ayudan en las búsquedas o consultas.

No tengo idea de como hacer esto y de como implementarlo ya que por decir tengo una columna don el tipo de dato `smallint()` pero como estoy viendo otra base de datos que ha sido creada en visual foxpro me surgió la curiosidad sobre este tema ya que en la tabla de la base de datos que se elaboró en visual en el índice que tiene se puede visualizar que se utiliza el comando `str()` en una columna que es numérica y esto beneficia para que la persona que este haciendo la consulta pueda ingresar un número cualquiera y poder buscar el dato.

He estado consultando en varios cursos relacionados con SQL pero hasta ahora se enfocan en una sola columna y no me entienden lo que se puede realizar en Visual Foxpro.

```
CREATE TABLE contacto (
...
...
...
...
primary key (id)
index datos, id, nombre, apellido, telf)
```

Esto es parte de lo que quiero lograr, pero hasta el momento tengo ha la línea de clave primaria

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar con algo ya que es con el fin de aprender sobre el uso completo de SQL o MySQL

Comment: No entendi nada de tu pregunta.. cual es la pregunta???

Comment: que como se pone en en un índice al crearlo que quieres transformar e dato a una cadena o string para que cuando se búsque los datos se puedan escribir; ejemplo en vfp tengo el índice id, nombre, correo los cuales están str(id,nombre,correo) lo que permite que tu busques por ciertos caracteres

Comment: Estas comparando peras (una db vpf) con bananas (una mysql)... igual, si eso es el caso, basta con transformar el indice a lo que queres.. no lo que no si suena a buena idea.. porque querrias buscar un numero como texto, si seguro como numero lo busca mucho mas rapido????

Comment: Creo entender lo que quieres hacer. Lo ideal es que los campos que uses con frecuencia para búsquedas como, id, nombre, apellido, como lo es tu caso, sean indexados y sean claves primarias, esto para optimizar las consultas. Ahora, lo que hablas del ingresar un valor de búsqueda ya queda de parte del lenguaje que utilices. Por ejemplo, puedes ingresar un numero de id como String, y convertirlo o parsearlo a Int que es el tipo de dato en tu tabla.